# Why are the /boot partition from Raspberry Pi and a EFI system partition (ESP) both formatted as a FAT32 partition?

Tags: boot, filesystem, partition

I understand that each processor has its own specific way of starting.

Fact is that both of them (RPi and UEFI boot) need a small FAT partition to boot, both around 100MB. Is there any reason for this **similarity**?

I have to say that in the beginning I was mixing them up. I thought that RPi /boot partition would be formatted as FAT because it would start using UFEI boot. After reading about RPi boot process ([here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10442/what-is-the-boot-sequence) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=6685)) realized that they were different things. (They are, right?)

[FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) file system is a legacy (meaning old) file system. Someone asked [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58502) the same question but as a good reason I only recognize that FAT file systems are **universally supported**. However is there any other good advantage of a FAT boot partition in comparison with any another file system? So that it justifies being used by two different and modern boot processes?

Thanks!

------> [Answer] after Topic was closed, I found this answer better: [Raspberry pi 3 - why the FAT partition?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44074/raspberry-pi-3-why-the-fat-partition) For me, there are 2 main reasons:

- Adding a normal [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) to the RPi would cost money, once it is usually stored on a flash memory (e.g. NAND flash). The objective is to produce a cheap computer, so the workaround was to store the Pi's equivalent BIOS files in a separate partition on the SD card, saving money.
- So now they needed to format the SD card in a way that is easy to implement a bootloader. FAT are easy/compact file systems. Others are better in many other points, but are more complex.

I would say that ESP partition is also formatted as FAT for the reason above. Also as written below, Microsoft is a member of the UEFI forum. And as listed [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5375.windows-file-systems.aspx#Windows_file_systems_formats) by Microsoft: "The File Allocation Table (FAT) file system is supported primarily to enable upgrades from previous versions of Windows, for compatibility with other operating systems in multiboot systems and as a format for flash drives or memory cards".

Answer (score 0):

FAT has following advantages

- it performs well for "small" filesystems
- its thoroughly tested, we know its weaknesess (as opposed to BTRFS)
- it is simple to parse and implement (as opposed to NTFS or HFS+)
- it is popular and supported nearly everywhere (as opposed to ExFAT or UDF)
- it is backwards-compatible to and supported by the whole Microsoft/x86 ecosystem (as opposed to ext4)

Many filesystems beat FAT on some points, but only FAT meets them all (esp. 3 and 5).

Don't forget that Microsoft being a member of the UEFI forum was almost mandatory due the significance of the the products and the company itself.